# find max Consecutive Ones in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers. I need to find the maximum number of consecutive 1s in the array.

```
var arr = [1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1];

const maxOne = (arr) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let count = 0;
    let result = 0;
    if (arr[i] ==1) {
      count += 1;
      result = Math.max(result, count);
    } else {
      count = 0
    }
  return result
  }
}

console.log(maxOne(arr));
```

desired output: `3`

my output : `1`

I am not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: Your code re-initializes `result` for each array element. It should not do that.

Comment: *maximum number of consecutive* .. and yet `3` is never consecutive from your input sample of `arr`?

Comment: @mardubbles there are three 1 values at the end of the array?

Comment: Ahh so `1s` is not a noun, and is literal. I see

Comment: Also, the function should probably `return result` instead of print it.

Comment: Code actually looks buggy on intuitiveness @VarunArya

Comment: Code needs to be rethought. Contains logical errors other than the one @Pointy pointed out.

Comment: @mardubbles could you give an example or explanation how can I improve the code

Comment: I could give the solution, if thats what you mean? I could but isn't the purpose of your question a thought exercise for you?

Comment: @mardubbles yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You algorithm works, you just did few misstakes:

- create variables outside of loop
- return after loop, not in it(it will break loop at first iteration)

```
const maxOne = (arr) => {
  let count = 0;
  let result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 1) {
      count += 1;
      result = Math.max(result, count);
    } else {
      count = 0
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
let arr=[1,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,12,1,1,1,1];
let count=0;
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  arr[i]==1 ? count+=1 :count=0;
}
console.log(count).
```

Comment: The `.` character at the end of the last line should be a `;`, making it: `console.log(count);`.

Comment: That was just a typo @GustavoSousa

Answer (score 0):

```
const numbers = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1];
const maxString = Math.max(...numbers.join('').split('0')); // remove zero items and convert 
// the sequential Ones to a string. After that Find the string with the largest number of characters.
console.log('max:', maxString.toString().length) // Take the string length
//3
```

```
you can use *Math.max.apply(Math, numbers.join('').split('0'))* instead of second line.
```