# Is there a fix to my array sometimes having the right length but sometimes not with a binary array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have a binary array and would like to count the longest number of 1s in a row with this function. In particular, when I use this value for nums like `[1,1,0,1]` it counts correctly.

```js
let nums = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];

var findMaxConsecutiveOnes = function(nums) {
  let val = 0;
  if (nums.length >= 1) {
    console.log(nums.sort().reverse());
    for (i = 0; i <= nums.length - 1; i++) {
      if (nums[i] === nums[i + 1]) {
        val++;
      } else {
        console.log(val);
        return val;
      }
    }
    console.log(val);
    return 0;
  }
};

findMaxConsecutiveOnes(nums)
```

Comment: Why are you sorting the array?

Comment: I thought that was the most effective way to do it, is there another way?

Comment: If you sort, you destroy the "in a row" characteristic.

Comment: I find a simple solution for that. look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75297154/6487558).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is made simple with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const maxConsecutiveOnes = (ns) => ns .reduce (
  ({max, curr}, n) => n == 1 ? {curr: curr + 1, max: curr >= max ? curr + 1 : max} : {max, curr: 0},
  {max: 0, curr: 0}
) .max

console .log (maxConsecutiveOnes ([1, 1, 0, 1]))
console .log (maxConsecutiveOnes ([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

We fold the array into a `{max: Number, curr: Number}` object, starting with `{max: 0, curr: 0}`.  At every step, if we have a `0`, we reset `curr` to `0` and keep `max`.  Otherwise we increment `curr`, and if that's larger than `max`, we use it for `max` as well.  At the end, we just extract the `max` property of our accumulated object.

Thus for example, we would go through these steps for `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]`:

| n | accumulator | notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - | `{max: 0, curr: 0}` | initial accumulator value |
| 1 | `{max: 1, curr: 1}` | increment `curr` and `max` |
| 1 | `{max: 2, curr: 2}` | increment `curr` and `max` |
| 0 | `{max: 2, curr: 0}` | reset `curr` to `0` |
| 1 | `{max: 2, curr: 1}` | increment `curr` |
| 1 | `{max: 2, curr: 2}` | increment `curr` |
| 1 | `{max: 3, curr: 3}` | increment `curr` and `max` |
| 0 | `{max: 3, curr: 0}` | reset `curr` to `0` |
| 1 | `{max: 3, curr: 1}` | increment `curr` |
| - | - | now we extract `max`, and return `3` |

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work if you sort it like you do for your `console.log()` on line 6.
If you don't want to alter you array, you should try with a copy that you sort. I think there are cases where you leave the loop. [1100111] makes you return val when you are at the zeros but you still have more ones after.
I'm not sure though, I didn't take time to check it.

Answer (score 0):

*If I understand correctly, you need to find the maximum consecutive 1s in the binary array.*

If not, ignore.

If yes,

As per your current code,

> Lets say, you have the 3 ones. 1,1,1 . The one at index 0 is equal to
> index 1. val becomes 1. Index 1 is equal to index 2. Val now becomes
> 2. It stops. Eventhough you have three consecutive 1s, you are printing only 2.

Now coming to the case of 1,1,0,1

> You should not be sorting it. Firstly it will group together all the
> 1s. In the case of [1,1,0,1] => when you sort, it is [1,1,1,0] => so
> it prints 3-1 = 2

In case of  [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

> It sorts to [1,1,1,1,1,0]. So prints 5-1=4

Try to do it without sort. One advantage is that you will not lose the max value. Second, you do not iterate the array twice(in case of sort, internally it iterates)

> So, you can perhaps try something to map through each element and keep
> a track of consecutive 1s. Keep a counter too. If you encounter 0,
> reset the counter. Also after incrementing and before resetting, check
> if the current sequence is greater than the max

This is one possibility. There could be more ways.

```
let nums = [1, 1, 0, 1];

var findMaxConsecutiveOnes = function(nums) {
  let val = 0;
  let max = 0;
  nums.forEach(el => {
      if(el == 1){
          val++;
          max = val > max ? val : max
      }
      else{
          max = val > max ? val : max
          val = 0;
      }
  })
  return max
};

findMaxConsecutiveOnes(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something nice and simple in a forEach loop:

```js
const binaryArray = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

const getMaxConsecutiveOnes = (arr) => {
  let countOfOnes = 0
  let maxConsecutiveOnes = 0
  arr.forEach(num => {
    if (num === 1) {
      countOfOnes ++
    } else if (countOfOnes > maxConsecutiveOnes) {
      maxConsecutiveOnes = countOfOnes
      countOfOnes = 0
    }
  })
  // Final check of which is longer to account for end of array
  return maxConsecutiveOnes > countOfOnes ? maxConsecutiveOnes : countOfOnes
}

console.log(getMaxConsecutiveOnes(binaryArray)) // expected output: 3
```